# adding actions to menus in bootstrapping

Tags: javascript, python, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a bootstrapping.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TEST</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Performance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book Library</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But here,

I want content to be filled by "this is performance" when performance is clicked and "this is book library" when library is clicked.

How can I add actions when clicking menus?

Comment: so you want to know how to attach actions on click of each menu item, right?

Comment: yes nishad I need to know how to do that so that my container will be changed.

Answer (score 3):

I have add ids to Performance and library buttons

```
<li><a href="#" id="Performance">Performance</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Library">Book Library</a></li>
```

here is a javascript snippet

```js
function click(e){
if(e.target.id=="Performance"){
document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].innerHTML="this is performance";
}
if(e.target.id=="Library"){
document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].innerHTML="this is library";
}
}
document.getElementById("Performance").addEventListener("click",click,false)
document.getElementById("Library").addEventListener("click",click,false);
```

```html
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Saurabh Shelar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" id="Performance">Performance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="Library">Book Library</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to attach just javascript/jquery functions to menu item, you can do it like this:

script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.nav navbar-nav li').click(function(){

    var name=$(this).attr('name')

    if(name=='performance'){

    //code to display data relevant to perfromance
    alert('this is performance')

    }
    else if(name=='library'){

    //code to display data relevant to library
    alert('this is library')

    }

    })

    })
</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li name='performance'><a href="#">Performance</a></li>
        <li name='library'><a href="#">Book Library</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Or if you want to attach server side actions on click of each menu item, you may need to change only the html part

html:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/path/to/action">Performance</a></li>
        <li><a href="/path/to/action">Book Library</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

you just need to add the action path to each menu item

Comment: Hi Nishad, thanks for the explanation. I do understand it little. But, I dont understand how to implement that. Can you paste code in pastebin so that I can understand connections?

Comment: I can guide, first download latest jquery from here https://jquery.com/download/. Then include the downloaded jquery in your html page just like including any other external javascript. Then copy paste the above javascript code inside your html body element. Next, add name attribute to <li> like I did it in the above html code. Thats it then you are done.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, add another attribute to your tag: "onclick"'

Give onclick's value the name of a function that you will create in javascript.
ex:
    `onclick="changeText()"`

So now you have ...
    `<li><a onclick="changeText()" href="#">Performance</a></li>`

Now, whichever content you want to get changed add this attribute to its tag:
    `id="perf"`

Now we need to write a little bit of javascript and create a function changeText() to handle what happens when performance is clicked.

```
<script>
function changeText() {
     document.getElementById("perf").innerHTML = "This is performance!";
}
</script>
```

Then you just do the same thing for the book library tag

Feel free to ask any questions if you are unclear :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did like you have guided, but still its not working. look at test.html http://pastebin.com/NKbsuge5 and test.js http://pastebin.com/C5HrLaxq